# Rspec - what is the best way to handle params in a Test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have a test on a method which takes a params hash, the total is 0 if it's not set in the params:

Item.rb:

```
  def set_template_values(params)
    self.set_nil_values
    self.template = 1
    self.deduction = 0
    self.tax_amount = 0
    self.tax_id = 0
    self.tax_rate = 0
    self.unclaimed_tax = 0
    self.cost = 0
    self.total = 10  
      if params[:total].to_i > 0
        self.total = params[:total]
      end
  end
```

Here is my test:

```
    let(:template_item){Item.new(:template_check => 'True' ,  
        :name => 'Gas' ,  
        :category_id => 1 ,  
        :sub_category_id => 24 ,  
        :job_id => 1, 
        :total => 10)}

  it 'Template Item' do
      template_item.set_nil_values
      template_item.set_template_values(template_item.attributes)
      template_item.save
      template_item.total.should be == 10
  end
```

I get this error:

```
  1) Item Template Item
     Failure/Error: template_item.total.should be == 10
       expected: == 10
            got:    #<BigDecimal:7fb9f316e270,'0.0',9(36)>
```

I can make it work if I do this in my test:

```
  template_item.set_template_values(:total => 10)
```

But I would rather set all the params when the item is created like in the real world.  Is there a specific way to pass in params?

Comment: Do you have any validation set up for your model? If so, `template_item.save` might not be saving the template_item. You will need to use `debugger` gem or something to inspect `template_item` after `template.save` to see its attribute values.

Comment: When I put the test before the save, it still fails, so it's not being set at all.  It works fine in production.  Also, it works when I explicitly set the value in the arguments, so there is a problem with passing "template_item.attrubues"

Comment: First problem: you're using "be == 10". Get rid of the == you're already checking for equality with "be".

Comment: @diego.greyrobot  Are you sure?  That raises an error:        expected #<Fixnum:21> => 10
            got #<BigDecimal:70160330601020> => #<BigDecimal:7f9ef32a6478,'0.1E2',9(36)>
       
       Compared using equal?, which compares object identity,
       but expected and actual are not the same object. Use
       `expect(actual).to eq(expected)` if you don't care about
       object identity in this example.
     # ./spec/models/item_spec.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: That's not an error, just the equality check failing because the values aren't the same. You can use either "be", "==", or "eq". But not both as you're doing. As far as your test failing, I'm not sure. Try inspecting the value of template_item.attributes does it contain the :total you're expecting? Inspect it by doing: puts template_item.attributes.inspect above your "should"

Comment: Looks like it's Rspec is converting it to a BigDecimal, but otherwise, its there: "total"=>#<BigDecimal:7fa282d3d4f8,'0.1E2',9(36)>